# iPhone app size limit

Tags: iphone

In AppStore Review Guidelines, the following point is given

Apps larger than 20MB in size will not download over cellular networks (this is automatically prohibited by the App Store)

Please clarify me is it .app file size or whole application file size

Comment: I think it's not a point to worry about. If your app crosses 20 MB, users will be asked to download it only on the Wi-Fi network and the 3G download would be disabled. Lots of games available on the App store are of more than 20 MB in size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That size limit refers to the compressed IPA bundle, not the .app folder. You can get a rough idea of how big the IPA (as downloaded from the App Store) will be by zipping up the app.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum size for app store is 2GB.

I have worked on some apps that were slightly about 2GB and were rejected. Had to make it go below 2GB.

I suggest you make your app less than 2gb, then download the remaining stuff once the app is launched. Thats probably the only way you can go about distributing such a big app.

PS: unless  you do Enterprise builds, where there can never be a limit, except for the device on which you install it.

Answer (score 2):

The .app is just a folder with an extension that contains all the files related to your application, the .app is the "whole application".

Also, the max app size you can submit, if I'm correct, it's 2GB.